# How to remove "Failed to instantiate the default view controller" warning?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

Within my storyboard I don't have any VC with the Is Initial View Controller checked as I am instantiating and setting the window.rootViewController programmatically within the app delegate.

My app is working perfectly however I want to remove the "Failed to instantiate the default view controller" message.

I found question regarding this on SO and the accepted answer stated that the warning will go away if the Main Storyboard File Base Name is removed from the info.plist ([Programmatically set the initial view controller using Storyboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428629/programatically-set-the-initial-view-controller-using-storyboards)).

However my app does not have the Main Storyboard File Base Name entry in the info.plist, so is there something else I can do to remove this warning?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Select a random VC in your storyboard as the initial VC. This will cause the warning to go away and the option will be overridden by your code inn AppDelegate. This is the approach I use to remove the warning. Maybe more of a workaround, but it is simple and works great :-)

Comment: So there are no allocation type issues with this? Would overwriting the window.rootViewController programmatically cause the retain count of the random VC to decrement?

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar question. Here the answers worked perfectly for me. Please check it out.
[iOS 7 - Failing to instantiate default view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875823/ios-7-failing-to-instantiate-default-view-controller)