# cannot instantiate default view controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, viewcontroller

I have recently had an app rejected by Apple  and when i attempted to make changes, my Main.storyboard was missing. I managed to delete the current reference and add an older version. After some tweaking, I restored the storyboard. (ALWAYS HAVE BACKUPS, KIDS)

I tried to run the new version, XCode could not find the first ViewController.

> 2014-09-13 22:18:42.453 Pong![1313:60b] Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?
>   Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination.

I have checked the box "Is initial ViewController" but to no avail.

Comment: Click on your project file in the `Project Navigator` pane at the top left, then click on the general tab and see that the `Main interface` has the same name written as the new storyboar name.

Comment: The box reads "Main" and is identically spelled to the new file, in terms of case too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 7 - Failing to instantiate default view controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875823/ios-7-failing-to-instantiate-default-view-controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a new Storyboard file then copy it, then change the Main Interface option to the new one. The old "Main" was deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I too have faced the same problem while working in `UINavigationController` and `segue`.

The reason for this error is, the `X-code` complier can't able to find the **initial starting view controller**.

Solution:

There is no need to create new storyboard. Just select the view controller in your current story board which you wanna to make as initial one.Then click Attribute inspector icon on top right corner and make a tick of `Is initial view controller`.

Now Rebuild and Run app.