# Starting out with storyboards, root view controller has a black screen. why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, storyboard

just started using story boards. I have created a empty application and a storyboard named storyboard. On this I have dragged on a navigation controller which is connected to a table view controller. The table view controller is set to root.

In the AppDelegate.m I have removed the window init code from application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, so I just have:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:      (NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

//This is empty as the storyboard will create a window for the app
return YES;}
```

In the targets for the app I have selected Storyboard.storyboard as the main interface. So when I run the app I just have a black screen and the message: 2014-12-17 16:18:58.884 Colorboard[35720:1793105] Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Storyboard' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?

Not sure why this is. Can someone please help? Sorry bit of a newbie with this stuff. thanks!

Comment: Select the navigation controller on the storyboard and in the Attributes Inspector enable Is Initial View Controller

Comment: Thank you!, just noticed that! Will try harder next time before submitting a question!

Comment: This may be helpful for you . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875823/ios-7-failing-to-instantiate-default-view-controller

Comment: Thank you for that, all fixed now.