# How to fix scene error?

Tags: ios, swift

Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier for runtime access via -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:.

What should i do for this error?

Answer (score 1):

Select the ViewController in your Storyboard which is not accessible and add a Storyboard ID[image]

Comment: there is no scene error after i did what you said , but now there is a "Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set? " error.

Answer (score 0):

That's only a warning. If you use that scene ignore the warning, otherwise delete this scene, because nobody needs it.

Comment: there is no scene error after i did what you said , but now there is a "Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set? " error. –

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when a View Controller/Scene does not have a segue to it and neither there is a identifier defined for the ViewController/Scene.

So basically XCode is complaining that though you have created a Scene, you can not use it in any possible way.

So depending on your need:

1) You may need to define a segue to it(may be with an identifier)

OR

2) Define Stoaryboard ID to it. By selecting scene -> Right Pane -> Identity Inspector(3rd Icon) -> Stoaryboard ID

OR

Ignore it for now.

Comment: there is no scene error after i did what you said , but now there is a "Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set? " error. –

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875823/ios-7-failing-to-instantiate-default-view-controller

This might help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do like this one.

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("firstView") as ViewController
        self.presentViewController(viewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

[image]