# Changing the initial screen on ios

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uistoryboard

i am trying to add a login screen to my app but when i tried changing the initial view controller to the login screen but when i change the initial view controller pointer it has no effect. 
I have tried the suggestions in:

[iOS 7 - Failing to instantiate default view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875823/ios-7-failing-to-instantiate-default-view-controller) 
but they did not work for me.
the first screen under the navigation controller is instead showing which was the intended initial view before the login was added.

[image: Storyboard screenshot]

**App Delegate**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let centerViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as!ViewController

    let drawerViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DrawerViewController") as!DrawerViewController

    let leftSideNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: drawerViewController)
    let centerNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)

    centerContainer = MMDrawerController(centerViewController: centerNav, leftDrawerViewController: leftSideNav)

    centerContainer!.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView;
    centerContainer!.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView;

    //works when i comment out this but navigation does not work then
    //window!.rootViewController = centerContainer
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()



    return true
}
```

Comment: Check `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, maybe u set the window and rootViewController with code already.

Comment: @Justlike i have added code from the Delegate class needed for the navigation

Comment: The config of storyboard would be **ignored** if you config the `window` with code.

Comment: See, `window!.rootViewController = centerContainer`.  So it is. `centerContainer` will be `the initial view controller` whatever you set with storyboard. @Lonergan6275

Comment: @Justlike ya i just noticed that but if i comment it out the initial view works but the nav drawer no longer works? should it work if I set `window!.rootViewController = centerContainer` after login?

Comment: Adjust your storyboard like this. @Lonergan6275  [http://i.stack.imgur.com/eYjkS.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eYjkS.png)

Comment: @Justlike If i do as you suggest wont the login be part of the main navigation then? i want login before the user sees the rest of the app and shouldnt be  in the menu after that

Comment: As you said, set `window!.rootViewController = centerContainer` after login will work.