# Do I still need to set the entry point? (Initial view controller)

Tags: ios, swift2

I'm setting the rootViewController of the window programatically, like this (`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` under `AppDelegate`'s `application` method):

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginScreen")

window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

if let window = window {
    window.rootViewController = rootViewController
}
```

Am I still required to go in the Interface Builder and set that controller as initial view controller? I get `Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?`
 If I set an entry point I have no problem and the error disappears. I want to know what is the correct way of programatically loading views. It's weird to set the rootViewController both programatically and by interface builder. Note that I am a beginner.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875823/ios-7-failing-to-instantiate-default-view-controller

Comment: duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875823/ios-7-failing-to-instantiate-default-view-controller

Comment: I've almost run out of solutions. I've already checked those questions so I don't think this is a duplicate.

Comment: If you're using storyboard anyway, forget the code and set the entry in Interface Builder.

Comment: I won't use Segues so setting the rootViewController programatically would do the trick. I think that setting the entry back will be the final decision. It's just weird, this is why I asked this.

Comment: As you mention *I am a beginner* why do you want to start with the advanced stuff? ;-)

Comment: I'm on iOS since one year. I coded many applications, but I still consider myself a beginner if I encounter this kind of problems. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the tick mark 'Is Initial View Controller' in controller properties, And then clean and run.
If still exists, please try this

```
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController;
```