# Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[image]
I just learn iOS about 2 days, and I cannot solve the problem with initial view controller

I google the problem and make sure I check the `Is Initial View Controller` but nothing show's with the console error:

> Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?

can someone help me please thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that is `main.storyboard` not `launchscreen.stroyboard` ?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini I am sure that is `main.storyboard `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875823/failed-to-instantiate-the-default-view-controller-for-uimainstoryboardfile-main)

Answer (score 1):

To solve, clean your build folder. Go to Product -> Clean Build Folder

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation, and I tried many things, but it didn't work. So I finally deleted the project and made a new one. Then the problem went away. I don't know why it happened, but anyway, I can progress my learning.

Answer (score -1):

All story board need an entry point (where to start and it looks like you did not define it . you need to add an arrow to let the storyboard know which vc is the initial viewcontroller [How to add arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqA8n.png)