# How to get rid of "perhaps the designated entry point is not set?"

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I'm using Xcode version 12.0.1. Currently I'm working on coordinator and I found this error:

`Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?`

To solve this error I tried from this also: [Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875823/ios-7-failing-to-instantiate-default-view-controller)

I created new story board but still can't solve.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the reason for this error would come if you have not ticked the initial view controller checkbox.

[image]