# View Controller Keeps Disappearing

Tags: xcode, xcode5, file-management

Whenever I close Xcode and then open it again, some file gets deleted and I have to start all over again. When I checked the file status it says locally deleted. Is there a way I can fix this :
[image]

Thanks

Comment: I doubt there's enough information here to diagnose your problem.

Comment: Are you storing this in a github repo by chance? I've had some strange things happen with pods lately.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that your 'red' files (classes) are not at the same location as they were the last time you opened the project.

1. Find the files which were red, add them back to your project, and
   delete the red links. Assuming, that you haven't deleted them by
   mistake. (in case you did accidently - here's a [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874174/recovery-deleted-files-from-xcode))
2. Check the full path of the missing file or 'Show in Finder'. Can  you access it?

   [image]

If this doesn't help, I found this useful thread when I was using Xcode 4.1 earlier. [Check it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409015/app-file-appears-in-red-missing-in-new-projects-with-xcode-4).